# Function that takes array of strings and returns the longest one

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

Trying to get this to work, but CodeBlocks gives me this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'max(char[4][10], int)'

Tried getting rid of `template <>`, made function to receive `char*`, nothing works.

How do I make this function to receive an array of strings (`char[]`), and spit out the longest one?

**EDIT**: Yeah, I missed that thing with index, now corrected. The problem is not gone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<class number>
number max(number numbers[], int n)
{
    number maximum = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > maximum)
            maximum = numbers[i];
    }
    return maximum;
}

template<>
char* max (char** strings, int n)
{
    int maxlen = strlen(strings[0]);
    int maxind = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (strlen(strings[i]) > maxlen)
        {
            maxlen = strlen(strings[i]);
            maxind = i;
        }
    }
    return strings[maxind];
}

int main()
{
    char strings[4][10] = {"Cat", "Dog", "CANNIBALS", "Witch"};
    int test_int[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    double test_dble[5] = {1.2, 3.1, 5223e11, 23, -1000.0};
    std::cout << "int max(): " << max(test_int, 4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "double max(): " << max(test_dble, 5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "char** max(): " << max(strings, 4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C++. Stop using `char*` and get on board with `std::string`. You should also steer towards `std::vector` and away from fixed-length C arrays which are fraught with problems.

Comment: Tip: In conventional C style, function calls look like `f(...)` with no intervening whitespace. The spaces are often reserved for non function calls like `for (...)`

Comment: Hint: What happens when you index an array of multiple strings with the *length of a random string*? If you want to return the longest string, you should have a separate variable to capture that, as well as the length.

Comment: The `1` in `maximum = strlen (strings [1]);` looks jarring. I'd take a closer look at it.

Comment: You have no char **'s in your program to pass to your attempted max implementation. A native 2D array is most decidedly not a double pointer nor convertible to one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we simplify your code a lot we can boil it down to this:

```
#include <cstring>

char* max(char** strings, int n) { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    char strings [4][10] = {"Cat","Dog","CANNIBALS","Witch"};
    max(strings, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

As Avi Berger pointed out `char[4][10]` isn't convertible to `char**`. The following would compile:

```
#include <cstring>

char* max(char (&strings)[4][10], int n) { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    char strings [4][10] = {"Cat","Dog","CANNIBALS","Witch"};
    max(strings, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this is only useful for `char[4][10]`, you could make it more generic like this:

```
#include <cstring>

template <int a, int b>
char* max(char (&strings)[a][b], int n) { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    char strings [4][10] = {"Cat","Dog","CANNIBALS","Witch"};
    max(strings, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Now that we have `a` and `b` there is no point in passing in `n`, it might as well reduce to this:

```
#include <cstring>

template <int a, int b>
char* max(char (&strings)[a][b]) { return nullptr; }

int main() {
    char strings [4][10] = {"Cat","Dog","CANNIBALS","Witch"};
    max(strings);
    return 0;
}
```